# SQL Server Select into variable not null when expected to be null (info)

Tags: sql-server, select

This is not a question but rather some SQL Server information I recently learned that was driving me crazy. I'm sure plenty of others (most?) here already know it, but just in case, maybe it will save someone hours of debugging. Take this example:

```
create table test1 (field1 varchar(16), field2 int);
insert into test1 values ('helloworld', 1);
declare @field2 int;
select @field2 = field2 from test1 where field1 = 'helloworld';
select @field2 'firstTime';
select @field2 = field2 from test1 where field1 = 'worldhello';
select @field2 'secondTime';
```

I expected *secondTime* to be null because the row was not found. But in fact it carried over from the previous select! You would need to either use if exists or set @field2=null before the second select.

Like I said, most of you probably already know this, but maybe it will help someone.

Comment: Nothing returned, nothing assigned. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7926b38fd4929794cd6ccc69b5c64fd2

Comment: To avoid this surprise, use `SET` instead of `SELECT` for scalar value assignments: `SET @field2 = (SELECT field2 FROM test1 WHERE field1 = 'worldhello');`

Comment: Your misunderstanding here is that you thought that a query that returns no rows returns a *`NULL`*, it does not. A query that returns no rows does simply that, returns no rows. To return a *`NULL`* you need to return at least 1 result.

Comment: Now they tell me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was suggested by a commenter the correct way is to use something like:

```
SET @field2 = (SELECT field2 FROM test1 WHERE field1 = 'worldhello');
```

See other comments for explanations.